# Minimum start date of datepicker

Tags: javascript, wix, velo

Sorry to do this guys, I have zero experience with Java or wix code, you would expect something as basic as what I am after would have a default in built setting for.

I have a date picker on a form, I want the minimum to be now()+3 - but have no idea where to start.

I did read a post that offered the below code:

```
   $w.onReady(function () {

   let today = new Date();
   let startDate = new Date(today);

   startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 3); 
   let endDate = new Date(today);

   endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1); // End Date +1 month from today //
   // Set min & max dates //

   $w("#datePicker1").minDate = startDate;
   $w("#datePicker1").maxDate = endDate;
   });
   });
```

However I appear to get this error message:
public/pages/qepnx.js/qepnx.js: Unexpected token (15:0)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much pain I've figured it out, it turns out JS is a lot less forgiving than languages like VBA, `{` or `(` incorrectly placed parenthesis will throw the whole code out which I learnt the hard way.

Code as below:

```
   $w.onReady( function() {

   var badDate1 = new Date();
   badDate1.setDate(badDate1.getDate());

   var badDate2 = new Date();
   badDate2.setDate(badDate2.getDate() + 1);

   var badDate3 = new Date();
   badDate3.setDate(badDate3.getDate() + 2);
   $w("#datePicker1").disabledDates = [badDate1, badDate2, badDate3];
   })
```

I'm sure someone who actually knows JS will be appalled by this, but it's simple code and does the job

Thanks